# How to partition a hard drive using C#

Tags: c#, .net, partitioning

I am familiar with the WMI method of formatting a partition but what if I wanted to create a partition programmatically? Is this possible and if so, can someone point me in the right direction because I am having the toughest time finding information about this. Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, but it doesn't look promising: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/996f3bc3-c80f-44b7-9ffe-806ba8be060a

Comment: Can't you just call the WMI functions to do it? Or are you looking for something like a `Disk.Format("C:")` in the .NET Framework libraries?

Comment: WMI is programmatic, last I checked.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably just want to use `Process.Start` to call diskpart with the arguments/script you need to partition the disk:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx